# Docker volume looks not mounted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Now I'm using docker-compose for developing on local.

I use docker-compose and I want to mount html, js, css files for synchronizing local file changes to docker file.

My local file structure is

```
MY_PROJECT
 |
 -views (contain html files)
 |
 -static
```

and
dockerfile is

```
ENV APP_DIR $GOPATH/src/MY_PROJECT
RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR

# Move all file to under GOPATH directory
ADD . $APP_DIR

RUN cd $APP_DIR && dep ensure -vendor-only

RUN cd $APP_DIR && go test ./...
RUN cd $APP_DIR && go build main.go

# Run the outyet command by default when the container starts.
ENTRYPOINT (cd $APP_DIR && ./main)

# Document that the service listens on port 8080.
EXPOSE 8080
```

and 
docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3'
services:
  PROJECT_NAME:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
       - ./views:/go/src/MY_PROJECT/views
    command: bash -c 'cd src/ltdws
```

When exec docker-compose up, and see kitematic, actually Volumes looks mounted.

[image]

But, even if I change html files under /views and saved
 it, nothing changes in docker.

Does anyone know if there are any problems?

---

Note : 2018/04/05 13:00
I found that js file looks mounted properly. I changed js files and reload browse, it works ( without docker-compose restart)

Comment: Probably some client side caching? Or server side template caching?

Comment: `set noswapfile` or restart docker container

Comment: I think there are no cache problem. I already trying restart container and build again. but it doesn't change anything.
Also I set "disable cache" with Google Chrome.

Comment: Is there any other container mounting `./views` folder after you start `PROJECT_NAME` service?